# iterate over a map of shared pointers without increasing the reference count?

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, shared-ptr

I would like to know whether the following code will result in an **increase in the reference count** for each shared pointer, or whether the optimizer will be clever enough to recognize that we are not in fact **copying** the pointer, just **dereferencing** it.

```
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<foo>> map;

...

for (auto kv : map)
    kv.second->func();
```

`kv` is a `std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<foo>>`

Since the range-based for-loop will return a stack-allocated `std::pair`, which in turn stores a **copy** of the `std::shared_ptr`, I believe that the reference count will be increased at this point.

However, it is plain to see that this copy is just temporary, and the intention here is not to copy ownership, but just dereference the currently owned copy.

But since the creation of the pair causes a a *side-effect*, an increase in the reference count, does this mean the optimizer will not be able to optimize this copy out, or have the compiler/optimizer writers recognized this use-case and been able to optimize out the copy?

Comment: This is why we have pointer containers. See boost::ptr_map. Here the container owns the pointer and thus there is no need to increment a reference count on use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The optimizer doesn't have the *right* to optimize it out, whether it could or not.

Within your loop, there are two copies of the same `shared_ptr`; one stored in `kv` and the other stored in `map`. There's no getting around the fact that there are two of them at that point.

If it *really* matters that much to you, you can store a reference rather than a copy, using `auto &kv`. That way, `kv` is a reference to the pair stored in `map`.

Comment: I would argue that unless you are dealing with fundamental types or if you explicitly want a copy, you should normally be using `auto&` or `const auto&`

Answer (score 1):

I would think it is a "good thing" to increment the reference count in this case.  Consider the following hypothetical code:

```
for (auto kv : map) {
    releaseAllOtherReferencesToAnyFooThatsNot(kv.second);  // Does what the name says.
    kv.second->tryToCauseACrash();
}
```

I would hope in this case, at least, kv.second would have a reference to the object to keep it alive.

Comment: Agreed, however in the context of my question this is not the case.

Comment: "releaseAllOtherReferencesToAnyFooThatsNot" In order to implement this function, you would have to change the contents of `map`, since it references the pointer. And if you do that, you've reached undefined behavior, since you have in all likelihood just invalidated the iterator that the range-based for loop was using.

Comment: @Nicol-Bolas I don't think you would have to change the map contents.  For example, you could simply do this:  `for (auto kv : map) kv.second.reset();`  I think this should leave the *pairs* in the map alone and should not invalidate the iterator.